# Relationships with @Embedded column

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have `@Embeddable` class for id:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Embeddable()
 */
final class Id
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $id;

    //getters, setters, etc
}
```

And two classes that have `@ManyToOne` relationship:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
final class Gist
{
    /**
     * @var Id
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Embedded(class="App\Entity\Id")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     */
    private $user;

    //getters, setters, etc
}
```

And `User` class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
final class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Id
     *
     * @ORM\Embedded(class="App\Entity\Id")
     *
     */
    private $id;

    //getters, setters, etc

}
```

When I trying to create schema I got error: `No mapping found for field 'id' on class 'App\Entity\User'.`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Doctrine` does not play well with `final` classes due to need for proxies. To quote them "An entity class must not be final or contain final methods." Could that be the root cause here?

Comment: No, without `final` still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no solution. https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/7094.

> Support of identifiers within @Embeddable is not really there yet, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use @Embeddable on id field. Cause it won't work. Declare your id field normally and it should work.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Gist
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    //getters, setters, etc
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    //getters, setters, etc

}
```

Also your Many-To-One relation is bad, see: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional

And never declare entities as final classes, see: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/architecture.html#entities